# Pegar conteúdo de formulário interno do site (POST)

Tags: php, post

Olá.
Agradeceria se alguém pudesse me dar uma ajuda, um caminho para solucionar esse problema.

Linguagem de programação: PHP.

Problema:
Quero trabalhar com informações de um site. Essa informação está no HTML da página do site o qual vou consultar todo dia tratar esse html, via php, e salvar as informações que eu quero no banco de dados da aplicação que estou criando.

O problema está em passar para o site o parametro que eu quero para ele carregar as informações que eu desejo. O que eu não sei é como passar um parametro via POST.

O site é o https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics.
Preciso passar o World e salvar o html todo da página em uma variável.
O fato de salvar o html da página e tratá-lo, isso eu já sei.

O problema está em como passar o parametro world para o link e ele carregar como se eu tivesse escolhido o World na página e clicado no botão Submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você criar um arquivo `index.php` e colar esse conteúdo
lá dentro e executar, vai aparecer a página do tibia. Até aí ok,
mas se entrar no Inspetor do google chrome e for no console
aparecerá uma mensagem...

Copie o código, execute e veja no seu console

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);


$init = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($init, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(["world"=>"antica"]),
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
]);
$r     = curl_exec($init);
$close = curl_close($init);

echo $r;
```

Esta é a mensagem, observe a mensagem em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra quem já usou o **Google Developer Console** sabe que quando você vai usar uma aplicação do Google, que no meu caso usei uma `OAuth Token`, eles pedem para você colocar um **endereço de redirecionamento** que após o usuário entrar com a sua conta do google e autenticar, o Google vai redirecionar para a sua página da internet e passará o token via `?token=blabla` query get. Eu penso que no facebook está acontecendo a mesma coisa, nunca usei, mas provávelmente é isso.

**Resumindo** Você teria que ter acesso á API que o dono criou lá no facebook.

No caso o facebook só vai aceitar requisições vindas de https://secure.tibia.com/ mas estamos utilizando http://localhost, entendeu ?

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado, Marcelo!